# CockroachDB pg_column_size retuning null

Tags: cockroachdb

I am currently using the pg_column_size to calculate the size of a row in the DB.
something like:

```
select pg_column_size(col1, col2, col3..... col10) from _table
```

Problem is when 1+ column value is null the whole function returns null.

Is there anyway to set a default value for each column within the function  to avoid getting null?

Comment: In Postgres you could use `select pg_column_size(_table) from _table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
select pg_column_size(<table_name>.*) from <table_name>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifically trying to select a subset of columns?

If you do `select pg_column_size(table) from table;`, it should work.

Comment: I don't know if it's because I am using cockroachDB but I am getting ERROR: column "table" does not exist

Comment: @user1984190 which version of CockroachDB are you on?